# Flashed an unsupported recovery to my phone, how can i exit recovery mode and proceed with normal boot?

Tags: root-access, recovery-mode, rom

Can someone help me to restore my leeco le s3?
I tried installing the latest TWRP for leeco le 2 on my leeco le s3 (since they are nearly identical). After entering fastboot mode, I ran this command:

```
fastboot flash recovery recovery.img
```

It performed operation, and said 'OK'. Then, I rebooted my device by holding volume up + power key. It started a normal boot and booted into android.
I ran command to flash again, then typed

```
fastboot reboot
```

My device powered off and did not power on again.
When I connect it to a windows pc via usb, windows keeps playing sound of connecting a device, then a second later - a sound of disconnecting device.
I did not flashed any ROM to my device, my guess is that I installed an unsupported recovery mode. Is there any way I can exit this recovery mode and proceed to the normal boot?
My device has a non-removable battery, Is there a way to power it off completely and boot normally, avoiding recovery menu?

Answer (score 1):

Press and hold all three buttons Volume Up, Volume Down and Power button for 15 seconds. This process Turn off your device after that wait a minute and power on your device by pressing power button only.